# Animate arrow with CSS or Anime js

Tags: css, animation, anime.js

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="38.607" height="16.397" viewBox="0 0 38.607 16.397">

  <g id="arrow-right" transform="translate(38.607 16.397) rotate(180)" opacity="0.504">
    <path id="Path_6553" data-name="Path 6553" d="M12.824,10.468a1.242,1.242,0,0,1,0,1.658l-5.716,6.2,5.717,6.2a1.243,1.243,0,0,1,0,1.658,1.023,1.023,0,0,1-1.529,0l-6.48-7.026a1.242,1.242,0,0,1,0-1.658l6.48-7.026a1.022,1.022,0,0,1,1.529,0Z" transform="translate(-4.498 -10.123)" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
    <path id="Path_6554" data-name="Path 6554" d="M5.625,17.955c0-.6.73-1.08,1.632-1.08H41.519c.9,0,1.632.483,1.632,1.08s-.73,1.08-1.632,1.08H7.257C6.355,19.035,5.625,18.551,5.625,17.955Z" transform="translate(-4.544 -9.757)" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="evenodd"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Hi, I want to create an animation for this arrow, the arrow should be filled with a different color from left to right. I tried several methods but couldn't find a proper solution. Can anyone point me to the correct way?

Comment: Do you have a gif that you want exactly?

Comment: @Pterrat , I don't have a gif but hoping this image will give an idea of what I need https://prnt.sc/kR6vp2NyxyAt

Comment: Would animating using SVG's dash-offset etc help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like that? I used `background` gradient and `background-position` to animate it with CSS and then [`mask-image`](https://caniuse.com/?search=mask-image) to mask it into an arrow shape.

```css
@keyframes gradient {
  0% { background-position: 0px 0; }
  100% { background-position: 150px 0; }
}

div {
    height: 64px;
    width: 150px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red 15%, blue 50%, red 75%);
    animation: gradient 1s infinite linear;
    -webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzOC42MDcgMTYuMzk3Ij4KICA8ZyBmaWxsLXJ1bGU9ImV2ZW5vZGQiIG9wYWNpdHk9Ii41MDQiPgogICAgPHBhdGggZD0iTTMwLjI4MSAxNi4wNTJhMS4yNDIgMS4yNDIgMCAwIDEgMC0xLjY1OGw1LjcxNi02LjItNS43MTctNi4yYTEuMjQzIDEuMjQzIDAgMCAxIDAtMS42NTggMS4wMjMgMS4wMjMgMCAwIDEgMS41MjkgMGw2LjQ4IDcuMDI2YTEuMjQyIDEuMjQyIDAgMCAxIDAgMS42NThsLTYuNDggNy4wMjZhMS4wMjIgMS4wMjIgMCAwIDEtMS41MjkgMFoiIGRhdGEtbmFtZT0iUGF0aCA2NTUzIi8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSJldmVub2RkIiBkPSJNMzcuNTI2IDguMTk5YzAgLjYtLjczIDEuMDgtMS42MzIgMS4wOEgxLjYzMkMuNzMyIDkuMjc5IDAgOC43OTYgMCA4LjE5OXMuNzMtMS4wOCAxLjYzMi0xLjA4aDM0LjI2MmMuOTAyIDAgMS42MzIuNDg0IDEuNjMyIDEuMDhaIiBkYXRhLW5hbWU9IlBhdGggNjU1NCIvPgogIDwvZz4KPC9zdmc+Cg==);
    mask-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I converted SVG to Base64 because I have no place (server) to store it (there may be a classic path to arrow.svg).